# How to package font-awesome with webpack for production distribution?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, font-awesome, webpack

I'm distributing a single javascript (and React) front-end to my customers. I've installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome-webpack and it works locally, but once I package it for distribution, the fonts go missing.

Here's my webpack configuration: https://gist.github.com/biznickman/e936538479856af2054a

So the questions:

- How do you package the font so it will be included in the distributed version?
- Also, is there an easier way to just package these items individually as SVG elements?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "when I package it for distribution"?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller if I use my development webpack everything works fine and dandy. But then once I compile it for distribution (as a single JS file) it doesn't work.

Comment: Check out this url: http://www.vimalselvam.com/2015/12/19/webpack-loader-for-fonts/
"Is there an easier way to just package these items individually as SVG elements" - sorry, it is impossible.

Comment: @NickONeill Right, but what I'm asking is what that entails. Reading your webpack config, I don't see any branching logic, meaning the same plugins and loaders are running no matter what, right? So are you saying it works in `webpack-dev-server` but not from a built file, or...?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller exactly. It works with "webpack/hot/only-dev-server" but not from a built file.

Comment: Are there any console errors when not on dev? If not, when running on the dev server, do you see the fonts or stylesheets in the web traffic anywhere? Does that match when not on dev?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller on dev server it shows it being loaded in the console. However on the web server it says `Failed to load resource: https://thedomain.com/test/db812d8a70a4e88e888744c1c9a27e89.woff2`

Comment: Hm. This is getting harder to solve on a Q&A type site as it looks like it will involve a bit of troubleshooting and we don't have access to your code. I know this is less helpful, but have you considered not packaging your fonts with webpack? Font Awesome is so popular that your users probably already have it cached from CDN, so bundling may *decrease* performance in general use cases.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller well I know for a fact the first client doesn't have FontAwesome included. To be honest, most sites don't (despite it being a popular add-on)

Comment: I just meant that unless you've *already* encountered a performance issue including it via a `link` in the `header`, it probably falls under "premature optimization". In other words, it might be a question or hypothesis but not yet a problem needing to be solved. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.